# Android beta pushing requirements

Tags: android

I am new to google dev console. I have an app, that is already released in playstore by someone. Now i am taking over the controll. There is a beta version in the google dev console. I am not good with dev console. Can any one tell me how to push new beta version of my app from android studio(ie, from building of apk). Whether i need signed apk or normal apk? Please clarify.

Answer (score 0):

To publish on play Console, you will need signed apk. Please refer https://developer.android.com/studio/publish/app-signing.html
for signing apk.

For releasing beta you can use Manage Releases option in play console for your app.
Please read https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/3131213
Manage Releases -> Manage Beta -> Set up open beta testing
. You may consider open beta option which anyone can join through playstore.

Comment: For signing the apk, i need keystore file which is used for older versions apk building. Right?